# How to restore tasks of ScheduledExecutorService after restart spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I wanted to ask how to restore tasks of ScheduledExecutorService after restart spring boot. I'm setting a few tasks which should be called once a day and how can I restore them after reset of spring boot app? is it possible if I have many of them? maybe some trick with saving to database and restoring after start every single time?